# trigger a Jenkins from bamboo

Tags: jenkins, bamboo

My requirement:
My build pipeline is in Bamboo and Test integration pipeline is implemented in Jenkins. So once CI pipeline is completed in Bamboo, there should be a trigger from Bamboo to Jenkins job.

I'm aware this can be done via API call to Jenkins, however I also saw that there is some kind of plugin in Bamboo which can integrate with Jenkins.
I could not find the name of that plugin anywhere, can someone of you help me is providing the plugin name ?
Please do let me know for more question.

Answer (score 0):

You might be referring to the following plugin: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211284/webhook-to-jenkins-for-bitbucket. However, this plugin is for Bitbucket and not Bamboo. As far as I'm aware, there is no Jenkins specific plugin for Bamboo.

There is however a generic webhooks plugin for Bamboo: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1220844/webhooks-for-bamboo, which can be configured to trigger Jenkins at the end of a build.